# Генерация перебором всех Ipv4 средствами linux или python в stdout

Tags: python, linux, список

Требуется сгенерировать перебором список всех возможных IPv4 построчно и направить на stdout в трубу. Как? спасибо

Comment: Вы осознаёте, что он будет весить около 60 гигабайт?

Comment: да, вполне, но лучше просто на вывод построчно для pipe и на обработчик без сохранения в список. впрочем, соглашусь и в файл

Comment: Что считается «всеми возможными» IPv4? Локалхост считается? Широковещательные типа 255.255.255.255 считаются? 0.0.0.0?

Comment: да, считаются и локальные

Comment: Тогда задача сводится к банальному перебору чисел от 0 до 2**32 и их форматированию. Какие проблемы у вас возникли при решении данной задачи?

Comment: Проблемы в моей малограмотности и некомпетентности порой в простейших вопросах (  пытался на коленке echo -e {000..255}.{000..255}.{000..255}.{000..255} | tr ' ' '\n' - не прокатило, но даже если и так, придется вырезать впереди стоящие нули. Уверен, что есть более грамотное и изящное решение

Comment: Малограмотность исправят учебники ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Форматирование с помощью socket.inet_ntoa:

```
import socket
import struct

for ip in range(2**32):
    print(socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack(">I", ip)))
```

Comment: работает, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы все возможные ipv4 напечатать:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import ipaddress

for ip in ipaddress.IPv4Network('0.0.0.0/0'):
    print(ip)
```

Answer (score 0):

Под ваши условия и такой скрипт подойдёт:

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((i=0;i<256;i++))
do
  for ((j=0;j<256;j++))
  do
    for ((k=0;k<256;k++))
    do
       for ((l=0;l<256;l++))
       do
         echo $l.$k.$j.$i
       done
    done
  done
done
```